Trouble with socket programming: Socket creation and binding returning errors in C
I'm working on a C program that involves socket programming basically I'm trying to write a simple HTTP server I'm noob to this, and I'm encountering issues with binding. I've written the following code, but I'm getting errors during binding. I've checked the code and can't seem to find the issue. Can anyone help me identify what's wrong?
when i run the program i get this output

here is my code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT "4390"

int main(){

        int status;
        struct addrinfo hints, *res;
        int sockfd;


        memset(&hints,0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

        if((status = getaddrinfo("localhost",PORT,&hints,&res) != 0)){
                fprintf(stderr,"getaddrinfo error: %s\n",gai_strerror(status));
        }


        if((sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,0) == -1)){
                fprintf(stderr,"socket error %s\n",gai_strerror(sockfd));
        }

        int bindstatus;
        if((bindstatus = bind(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen) == -1)){
                fprintf(stderr,"bind error %s\n", gai_strerror(bindstatus));
        }
        printf("%d\n",bindstatus);
        return 0;
}


your status,sockfd,bindstatus are logical 0|1 results of comparison and have nothing in common with statuses and file descriptors

Note that POSIX specifies the return value of  bind():
Upon successful completion, bind() shall return 0; otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.  So, once you fix the problem with assigning the result of a comparison to bindstatus, you need to report the error using strerror(errno) rather than trying to use gai_strerror().

The POSIX specification for gai_strerror() says: The gai_strerror() function shall return a text string describing an error value for the getaddrinfo() and getnameinfo() functions listed in the <netdb.h> header. You should not use gai_strerror() for the error response from socket() either: Upon successful completion, socket() shall return … Otherwise, a value of -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.

The main problem is caused by an attempt to write compact code without properly understanding operator precedence. In addition to that there are some other errors.
Take this part:
    if((sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,0) == -1)){
        ...report error
    }

What you attempt to do here is
    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        ...report error
    }

What you do instead is
    sockfd = ( socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,0) == -1 );
    if (sockfd) { ...

Thus, sockfd will not be the sockfd but be likely 0, because 0 means false and false is the result of a == comparison between what socket returned (the file descriptor) and -1.
Thus bind will be called later with a sockfd of 0, which isn't a valid socket. Thus bind will fail. In the code with bind you make the same kind of precedence error again.
The best way to fix is to write compact code only if you really understand what you are doing, in this case understanding operator precedence and properly applying parentheses where needed. I recommend instead to write more verbose code in order to avoid such easy to miss problems.

Apart from that gai_strerror does not expect the return value of socket or bind as input. It should not even be used to deal with the error of these functions, but is used for handling errors in getaddrinfo. See the documentation for details. What you likely wanted to use was strerror which takes errno as argument.

Your analysis is correct.  Note that int status = getaddrinfo("localhost", PORT, &hints, &res); if (status != 0) { … } is a safe way of writing the code — it initializes the variable as it is created. The compiler treats that the same as int status; if ((status = getaddrinfo("localhost", PORT, &hints, &res)) != 0) { … }, which is correct but there is a risk of mis-parenthesizing the code, as in the question.  If you have an if (…) { … } else if (…) { … } … else { … } sequence, then you can't introduce and initialize variables in quite the same way, and the assignment/comparison is OK.
